# Yii2 RBAC does not respect default role setting

Tags: yii2, default, role, rbac

I have a role called 'new'. While I don't explicitly set it, I want it to be the default role as soon as a user registers. I am using yii2-user and yii2-rbac extension by dektrium.

I have the following in my components...

```
'authManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
    'defaultRoles' => ['new'],
],
```

However, the following returns false...

```
if (Yii::$app->user->can('new'))
```

And the following returns an empty array too...

```
print_r(Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser( Yii::$app->user->identity->id ));
```

I am not sure where to look. I double checked and see the 'new' role properly set up in the RBAC configuration views.

Due to some reason, either Yii2 is not respecting my defaultRole config, or my expectation is wrong from that setting. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
Yii::$app->user->can('new')
```

should work (should return `true`), make sure you have not overrided `defaultRoles` somewhere else in application config (this is common mistake especially in advanced app).

I'd recommend check what `Yii::$app->authManager->defaultRoles` contains right before it. Seems like there are no your added `new` role.

In another words, RBAC respect `defaultRoles` option, so it's your mistake.

Also note that this:

```
Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser($userId);
```

returns all roles without default. This is by design.

However

```
Yii::$app->authManager->getRoles();
```

returns all roles including default.

Comment: Hi I did a print_r(Yii::$app->authManager->defaultRoles) and noticed that the array is empty. Due to some reason, it is not getting set. I tested on the Default/Index page. Any ideas.

Comment: @ShahidThaika Check if it's overridden by extensions you are using. Check their docs, maybe there is another way of setting it. What I wrote works perfectly without extensions.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think the extension respects that field, cause I just did a fresh install and test without any success.

Comment: @ShahidThaika I tested without these extensions too. What version of Yii2 you are using?

Comment: The latest basic version that composer downloads for me, not yii2-advanced. Hence, I am using dektrium for yii2-user and yii2-rbac.